# Unable to view image from ipfs link

Tags: nft, react, ipfs

I am trying to make dapp in which someone will upload an image and then the dapp will mint an nft for that image and then show the image.
But I am running into a problem. The dapp is generating a ipfs link but the link is to a folder which has the image in it and thus if i pass the ipfs link which i receive from the dapp to the component which renders the image then it doesnt show anything. How should i go about this in reactjs?
Here is the ipfs link-
[ipfs link](https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/bafybeia5zx6dvzy3v33bqaxeaoyersfxkhzmipjyfdk67g4xyh27txdibm/)

Comment: Maybe you are uploading the folder, upload the image only. What service are you using to upload?